# Can a Crystal Reports SQL Command be used with Mule?

Tags: crystal-reports, mule

Is there any reason a crystal reports report that uses a sql command cannot be used in Mule for reporting?

It just fails when I try and use it.  No error message that I can find.

Do I misunderstand what Mule does in this context?  Thanks.

Comment: Well no error message kinda make it hard. Try profiling on the server side and see if and what SQL gets to the DB.

Comment: Also how is CR called from Mule? Via a specific component? Does it use the Mule JDBC transport for data access?